# Python - manually removing a specific letter from a string

Tags: python, string

I'm aware of the `string.replace("x", "y")` method, but I'm trying to manually remove a character from a string to help me better understand Python and programming in general. The method I currently have is detailed below, but I can't understand why for "Dee" and removing "e" it will return "De", but for "John Do" and removing "o" it will return "Jhn D". Thus, it is removing two letters, but only one letter in the first.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```python
def remove_letter():  # Remove a selected letter from a string
    base_string = str(raw_input("Enter some text: "))
    letter = str(raw_input("Enter the letter to remove: "))  # takes any string size
    letter = letter[0]  # ensures just one character is used
    length = len(base_string)
    location = 0

    while location < length:
        if base_string[location] == letter:
            base_string = base_string[:location] + base_string[location+1::]  
            # concatenate string using slices
            length -= 1
        location += 1

    print("Result %s" % base_string)
```

Comment: What it is messing up is removing two _adjacent_ letters. Consider what happens to `location` when you remove the character at `location`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem oyu have is that you change the size of the string you want to remove the letter from, while removing the letter :
When you remove the first 'e' in Dee, you have location = 1, corresponding to the first 'e, but is now that of the second 'e'. After removing the e, at the end of the current loop, you have location = 2, and length = 2, so stop looping.

How to resolve the problem : Increase the location ONLY when you do not find the letter :

```
else:
    location += 1
```

This will prevent your loop from not checking the letter right after a removed letter.

If you need any more explanation, just ask.

Comment: Thanks! I should've thought about that

Answer (score 3):

Considering what khelwood and HolyDanna said, this might be a viable approach:

```
def removeletter(string, letter):
    out = ''
    for i in string:
        if not i == letter:
            out += i
    return out

altered_string = removeletter(string, letter)
```

EDIT - You could also easily extend this to work as the `str.replace()` method does, but only for single characters:

```
def stringreplace(string, letter, replacement):
    out = ''
    for i in string:
    if i == letter:
        out += replacement
    else:
        out += i
    return out

altered_string = stringreplace(string, letter, replacement)
```